# Running Gunicorn alongside Daphne on Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord, daphne

I have been following several different tutorials about how to set up gunicorn and daphne in parallel so that gunicorn can serve http to my django apps and daphne to my django channels app. However, I am now stuck on the welcome to nginx homepage and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

supervisor.conf

```
[program:example]
directory=/home/user/example/example
command=/home/user/envs/example/bin/gunicorn example.wsgi:application
user=user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/envs/example/bin/gunicorn-error.log

[program:serverinterface]
directory=/home/user/example/example
command=/home/user/envs/example/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 example.asgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
user=user
stdout_logfile = /home/user/example/bin/gunicorn-error.log
```

nginx/sites-availible/example.com

```
upstream app_server {
    server http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Let's Encrypt parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_ws;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }
location @proxy_to_ws {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue, please?